# Obtaining items in a List based off a specified value through "=" character

Tags: c#, .net, string, list

I have a list of values stored out of which I have added an equals sign to these values as "production" and "test" as shown below.

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();

            data.Add("app01=production");
            data.Add("app02 = test");
            data.Add("app03 = production");
```

Using this List say I want to Extract the values which is equal to "production" . Now using a string.contains method this can be done easilly but what I actually want to store is only the first part , for example I only want to store the values "app01" and "app02" in a seperate list and not "app01=production" and app03 = production" .

Any suggestions on how to go ahead ?

Here is my code so far

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> data = new List<string>();

            data.Add("app01=production");
            data.Add("app02 = test");
            data.Add("app03 = production");

            List<string> production = new List<string>();


            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                if (item.Contains("production"))
                {
                    production.Add(item); 
                }
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `Split` each string on the `=` character, check if the second part of the split contains `"production"`, and if it does, select the first part (into a `List<string>`) using some `System.Linq`:

```
List<string> production = data.Select(item => item.Split('='))
    .Where(part => part.Length > 1 &&
                   part[1].Contains("production"))
    .Select(part => part[0].Trim())
    .ToList();
```

**Example output**

```
production.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

[image]

---

If for some reason you don't want to use Linq, you can do it using a loop by finding the [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof) the equals sign and comparing the [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) of the item *after* the equals sign to `"production"`, and if it's a match, return the *first* part of the string up to the equals sign (using [`Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim) to remove any leading or trailing spaces):

```
List<string> production = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in data)
{
    var equalsIndex = item.IndexOf("=");

    if (equalsIndex > 0 && item.Substring(equalsIndex).Contains("production"))
    {
        production.Add(item.Substring(0, equalsIndex).Trim());
    }
}
```